# detect if a python function was activated with an assignment operator (and should return a value)

Tags: python, return-value, function-call

I have a function that can return values, but in order to do so it collects outputs from AWS (and it can be very large jobs, so it can take a long time and not always necessary).

Is there a way I can know, at run time, if the user has called my function with an assignment operator (i.e: `x = foo()`) or not (i.e `foo()`).

I know I can just add a flag, but the idea of checking the call during runtime seems elegant.

Thanks!

Comment: Your function would not behave like a black-box, since it cares about who is calling it and in what way. As a user of your function, I would expect to have some guarantees about how your function will behave. So, either it always explicitly returns something, or it never does, but not "sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't". If the two different "modes" of your function do intrinsically different things, then it should be split up into two functions. Maybe it would help if you explained the purpose of your function in greater detail?

Comment: No, there is not an easy way to achieve it. When you are doing `x = foo()`, `foo` is called **before** `x` exists, `foo` can't and does not know that it should return something. The only possible way to achieve this would be with static code analyzers, which are not quite "at run time". Your best bet, as Paul said above, is to refactor the code in a way that `foo()` does/should not care how it was called.

Comment: Thanks!
Maybe the term "at run time" is not correct here.
I had in mind some kind of Code-Inspector that can interpret if there should be a return value or not.
It is easy for me to change the code, but it has many users that won't know to add the flag right away.

Also, it seemed like a great opportunity to learn a new feature (:

@PaulM. - The code is an API to run many jobs in AWS. the function collects the outputs and logs at the end, and the user doesn't always needs it, and it has a big overhead

Comment: @TomerHochbaum It seems like the best solution would be for the user to pass in a flag, so they can choose to get the output logs or not.